Linking of nanoGUI in cmake as external project
I want to add a GUI to my program and am trying to use nanogui. I adapted my CMakeLists-file to be similar to the other external projects I've already included.
I can find the necessary header files, but when linking I get an ERROR:
"error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol [...]" for a multitude of nanogui functions. I suppose the error lies with linking the library, as I'm not sure how to adapt the configurations in the documentation to my code.
(#CONFUSION comments mark the lines where I suspect my error to lie)
My CMakeLists.txt:
####################################################################
### project setup ##################################################
####################################################################
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18 FATAL_ERROR)

# Define project and executable name
set(PROJECT_NAME MolecularSurfaces)
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME Surfaces)
project(${PROJECT_NAME} LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)


# Make sure binary directory is not the same as source directory
if(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL PROJECT_BINARY_DIR)
  message(
    FATAL_ERROR
      "In-source builds not allowed. Please make a new directory (called a build directory) and run CMake from there."
  )
endif()


# enable unit testing via "make test" once the code has been compiled.
include(CTest)

# OpenGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

####################################################################
### external projects ##############################################
####################################################################
# Add OpenGL, glfw, glad, glm and nanogui as external project
include(ExternalProject)

SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS /NODEFAULTLIB:\"libcmt.lib\")

set(libGLFW glfw)
ExternalProject_Add(${libGLFW}
PREFIX          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLFW}
GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git
GIT_TAG         3.3.4
GIT_SHALLOW     ON
UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1 # Do not update the external project if it is already downloaded
CMAKE_ARGS      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLFW}/install
                -DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF
                -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF
                -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
)

set(libGLAD glad)
ExternalProject_Add(${libGLAD}
PREFIX          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLAD}
GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad.git
GIT_TAG         origin/master
GIT_SHALLOW     ON
UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1 # Do not update the external project if it is already downloaded
CMAKE_ARGS      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLAD}/install
                -DGLAD_INSTALL:BOOL=ON
                -DGLAD_PROFILE:STRING="core"
                -DGLAD_ALL_EXTENSIONS:BOOL=ON
                -DUSE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DLL:BOOL=OFF
)

set(libGLM glm)
ExternalProject_Add(
    glm
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/glm
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/g-truc/glm.git
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
    UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1 # Do not update the external project if it is already downloaded
    CMAKE_ARGS  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLM}/install
                -DGLAD_INSTALL:BOOL=ON
                -DGLAD_PROFILE:STRING="core"
                -DGLAD_ALL_EXTENSIONS:BOOL=ON
                -DUSE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DLL:BOOL=OFF
    )

set(GLM_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLM}/install)


set(libNANOGUI nanogui)
ExternalProject_Add(${libNANOGUI}
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/nanogui
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/mitsuba-renderer/nanogui.git
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
    CMAKE_ARGS  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libNANOGUI}/src/nanogui
                -DGLAD_INSTALL:BOOL=ON
                -DGLAD_PROFILE:STRING="core"
                -DGLAD_ALL_EXTENSIONS:BOOL=ON
                -DUSE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DLL:BOOL=OFF
    )

    # Disable building extras for the external project
#CONFUSION: I suppose these 3 lines are supposed to be added to the above ExternalProject_Add
set(NANOGUI_BUILD_EXAMPLE OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(NANOGUI_BUILD_PYTHON OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(NANOGUI_INSTALL OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

#CONFUSION: I changed the structure (nanogui is added within dep -> therefor not necessary to add subdir?)
add_subdirectory(ext/nanogui)

#CONFUSION: I have no idea how to set this property:
# a) I cannot find the dependencies necessary here
# b) I don't know how this would work with my external projects above
# For reliability of parallel build, make the NanoGUI targets dependencies
set_property(TARGET glfw glfw_objects nanogui PROPERTY FOLDER "dependencies")

# SETUP GLFW
set(GLFW_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLFW}/install)
add_library(GLFW_LIBRARY OBJECT IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(GLFW_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_OBJECTS ${GLFW_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/glfw3.lib)
set_property(TARGET GLFW_LIBRARY PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${GLFW_INSTALL_DIR})

# SETUP GLAD
set(GLAD_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLAD}/install)
add_library(GLAD_LIBRARY OBJECT IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(GLAD_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_OBJECTS ${GLAD_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/glad.lib)
set_property(TARGET GLAD_LIBRARY PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${GLAD_INSTALL_DIR})

# SETUP nanoGUI
set(NANOGUI_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libNANOGUI}/src/nanogui)
add_library(NANOGUI_LIBRARY OBJECT IMPORTED)
# Various preprocessor definitions generated by NanoGUI
# add_definitions(${NANOGUI_EXTRA_DEFS})


#CONFUSION: the following lines are necessary according to documentation; but I cant find the definition of ${NANOGUI_EXTRA_INCS}, ${NANOGUI_EXTRA_LIBS}
# Include directories for NanoGUI
include_directories(${NANOGUI_EXTRA_INCS})

set_property(TARGET NANOGUI_LIBRARY PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${NANOGUI_EXTRA_LIBS})

####################################################################
### project files ##################################################
####################################################################

# list project files
# TODO when finishing project: list files explicitly as GLOB is not recommended
file(GLOB_RECURSE app CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/app/*.cu")
file(GLOB_RECURSE headers CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")
file(GLOB_RECURSE headers CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.hpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE headers CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.cuh")
file(GLOB_RECURSE sources CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE sources CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.c")


# Create a single .lib file containing our compiled objects, and the compiled objects of all other dependencies
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${app} ${headers} ${sources})


# Add all include file paths
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${GLAD_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${GLFW_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${GLM_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${NANOGUI_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/app
)

# Specify the order in which libs depend on each other
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${libGLFW} ${libGLAD})
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${libGLFW} ${libGLAD} ${libNANOGUI})
# target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} GLAD_LIBRARY GLFW_LIBRARY)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} GLAD_LIBRARY GLFW_LIBRARY NANOGUI_LIBRARY)

# copy shader files
# add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
#     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
#     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/shaders
#     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/shaders
#     COMMENT "Copying shaders into binary directory")

add_custom_target(copy_shaders ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/shaders
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/shaders
    COMMENT "Copying shaders into binary directory")

add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} copy_shaders)
####################################################################
### cuda configurations ############################################
####################################################################
# Request that particles be built with -std=c++17
# As this is a public compile feature anything that links to
# particles will also build with -std=c++17

target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:
                        # --generate-line-info
                        --device-debug
                        --use_fast_math
                        # --relocatable-device-code=true
                        >)
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-G>)


# Set CUDA architecture
# default value: 75 to match testing system with nvidia 2080 card

if(NOT DEFINED ${CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES})
  set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 75 CACHE STRING "CUDA architectures" FORCE)
endif()
message(STATUS "CUDA architectures set to ${CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES}")

# We need to explicitly state that we need all CUDA files in the
# particle library to be built with -dc as the member functions
# could be called by other libraries and executables
set_target_properties( ${PROJECT_NAME}
                       PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON
                       CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS ON
                       )



# add executable
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}  app/main.cu)

target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${GLAD_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${GLFW_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${GLM_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${NANOGUI_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${GLAD_C_DIR}
)

set_property(TARGET ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
             PROPERTY CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON
             CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS ON
             )
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME})

Here is one error line as example:
[build] main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl nanogui::Object::inc_ref(void)const " (?inc_ref@Object@nanogui@@QEBAXXZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl nanogui::ref<class nanogui::Screen>::ref<class nanogui::Screen>(class nanogui::Screen *)" (??0?$ref@VScreen@nanogui@@@nanogui@@QEAA@PEAVScreen@1@@Z) 

I checked all the paths for nanogui (include dir etc) to make sure the header files in my code can be found (and they could be found). As soon as I use them (create gui elements and draw), the errors start appearing.
